# Show div depending click's location on previous page

Tags: javascript

I have 4 forms on my contact page and each of them is showing by clicking on a independant div block.

*( For example : "Become Partner" form is showing when user click on the div block with ID "partner-div" )*

In order to avoid that the user has to click everytime on the correct div block to see the concerned form, I would like to ensure that the form is displayed when the page loads by clicking on a div block or button on the previous page.

I know i've to do this with **document.referrer** but i'm not very good with Javascript.

Basically, this is the kind of script i'm looking for :

*If user clicks on the button with the ID "blabla" on the previous page, then click on the button with the ID "showform" on the current page"*

I hope you've understand my issue

Comment: Why not put the information in the URL?

Comment: @NicoHaase Problem is, i don't know how to write the script with document.referrer because i'm not good with Javascript ( i'm more a graphic designer than a web developer ) i'll be glad if you can do that 

Comment: Feel free to skip the referer part. Add the information about which div to open to the URL and read it from there